# Find the invertible solutions of $x^{-1}+x=0$ over a ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, finite-fields

Let $(R, +, \times)$ be a finite ring with identity $1$. There are two notations:The set of all invertible elements in $(R, \times)$ and the set of all nonzero elements in $R$, are denoted by $R^\times$ and $R^*$, respectively.

I am considering the following problem.

> Solve the equation over $R^\times$: $x^{-1}+x=0$.

I have tried the following:

Suppose the multiplicative order of $e$ is $r$, denoted by $r=\text{ord}(e)$. It means that $x^r=1$. Then $x^{-1}=x^{r-1}$. The equation now is $x^{r-1}+x=0$.

Since $x$ is invertible, the equation now is $x^{r-2}+1=0$.

Then it has $x^{r-2}=-1$. Squaring both sides, we get $x^{2(r-2)}=1$ which implies that $r\mid 2(r-2)$. Equivalently, $4\mid r$.

Case 1: $R$ is a finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$. Then $-1=g^{\frac{q-1}{2}}$ and $x=g^i$ for some $1\le i\le q-1$, where $g$ is a generator of $\mathbb{F}_q^\times$. The equation now is $g^{i(r-2)}=g^{\frac{q-1}{2}}$. That is $i(r-2)\equiv \frac{q-1}{2}\pmod{q-1}$. Then it has solutions for $i$, if and only if, $\frac{q-1}{2}\mid\gcd(r-2, q-1)$. And then
$$\gcd(r-2, q-1)=\begin{cases}q-1 \\
\frac{q-1}{2}
\end{cases}$$
If $\gcd(r-2,q-1)=q-1$, then $(q-1)\mid (r-2)$. it is a contradiction since $r \mid (q-1)$. If $\gcd(r-2,q-1)=\frac{q-1}{2}$, then we have $\frac{q-1}{2}\mid (r-2)$. Let $k_1\ge0$ and $k_2\ge 0$ be two integers such that 
$$r-2=k_1\frac{q-1}{2}, q-1=k_2r.$$
We have $(2-k_1k_2)r=4=1\times 4=2\times 2 =4\times 1$. To solve the equation of two variables $k_1,k_2$ and $r$, we get two solutions:(If $r=1$, then $k_1k_2=-2$ which is a contradiction.)

1. $r=4, k_1=k_2=1$
2. $r=2,k_1=0$ and $2k_2+1$ is a prime power.

To sum up， we have
$$\{x\in \mathbb{F}_q^\times \mid x^{-1}+x=0\}=\begin{cases}
\{2,3\}, & q=5\\
\{1,-1\}, &q=2k+1,
\end{cases}$$

Case 2: $R$ is a residual class ring $\mathbb{Z}_n$. No ideas....

=====================================================

PS: the trying over finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$ is failed after I run the following Magma code：

```
for q in [2..1000] do
    if not IsPrimePower(q) then
        continue;
    end if;
    fq:=GF(q);
    solutions:={x: x in (Set(fq) diff {0}) | ((x)^(-1)+(x)) eq 0};
    if #solutions gt 0 then
        print q, #solutions, solutions;
    end if;
end for;
```

The code gives many counterexample such as, for $q=13$, the solutions should be $5$ and $8$. And the numeric experiment evidences that

1. When $2\mid q$, the only one solution would be $x=1$;
2. Otherwise, it has exactly two solutions $x_1$ and $x_2$ such that $x_1+x_2=0$.

Now I have no ideas at this moment. Maybe it is hard to answer this problem. It would be easier if the ring is residual class ring $\mathbb{Z}_n$ or finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$.

Or, there is a posibility that the problem was well-studied and the result is unknown for me. Then please give me some keywords or conferences.

Thanks for any replies.

Comment: From $x^{-1}+x=0$, we have $x^{-1}=-x$, thus: $-x^2=1$, which implies $\text{ord}(x)|4$.

Comment: What does the question mean? What kind of answer are we supposed to give? In general, there can be many solutions, or no solutions... Are you sure there was nothing given about $R$? Or about the expected form of the solution? The answer of solvability is well-known in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ for $p>2$ prime. If $p\equiv 3 \pmod 4$, then there is no such element, as the equation $x^2\equiv -1 \pmod p$ has no solution. If $p\equiv 1 \pmod 4$, then there are exactly two solutions of the equation $x^2\equiv -1 \pmod p$, but again, hard to describe them.

Comment: This most certainly depends on the underlying ring. For example in quaternions $\mathbb{H}$ there are **infinitely** many solutions to (the equivalent equation) $x^2=-1$, see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion#Square_roots_of_%E2%88%921

Comment: @freakish Thanks. In the question, only finite rings are considered.

Comment: @A.Pongrácz It seems that the number of solutions is not greater than 2. So I prefer the constructive result. You mentioned that there can be many solutions. Could you give an example in which the number of solutions is greater than 2. Note that the ring is finite and has an identity 1. For generic case, there should be something about $R$, but I can not find it out.

Comment: @Qurultay Together, we have $\text{ord(x)}=4$. great! There is no solutions if $4\nmid |G^\times|$.