# Does there exist an element of order 4 in a finite ring with characteristic 2?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, finite-groups

It is obvious that every nonzero element in finite field $\mathbb{F}_{2^n}$ has an odd order. So I was wondering if the following conjecture was true or false.

Notations: Let $(R,+,\times)$ be a **finite** ring with an identity. The characteristic of ring $R$ is denoted by $\text{char}(R)$. The multiplicative order of an invertible element $e$ is denoted by $\text{ord}(e)$. The set of all invertible elements is denoted by $R^\times$.

> If $\text{char}(R)=2$, then $\text{ord}(e)\equiv1\pmod{2}$ for any $e\in R^\times$.

For a weaker conjecture, we have

> If $\text{char}(R)=2$, then $\text{ord}(e)\not\equiv 0\pmod{4}$ for any $e\in R^\times$.

For $R=\mathbb{F}_{2^n}$, the conjecture is true. However I think characteristic and multiplicative order are two independent matters. Because I know few rings $R$ with $\text{char}(R)=2$. Could anyone prove or disprove any of the two conjectures?

PS: the problem is araised from [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3033809/find-the-invertible-solutions-of-x-1x-0-over-a-ring), in which I need to find out all the elements of order $4$.

=======================

Thanks to user26857 and Jyrki Lahtonen. The two conjectures are false.

For any $p$ and $d$, consider the ring $R=\mathbb{F}_p[x]/(x^d-1)$ and the coset $e=x \in R$. Then the multiplicative order of $e$ is $d$.

- Letting $p=2$ and $d=4$, it disproves the first conjectrure.
- Letting $p=2$ and $d=2$, it disproves the second conjectrure.

Comment: What about $R=\mathbb F_2[X]/(X^4-1)$ and $e$ the residue class of $X$? (If this does not work then maybe I misunderstood your question.)

Comment: user26857's example can be rewritten to say the same about the coset of $1+x$ in $\Bbb{F}_2[x]/\langle x^4\rangle$ (this example is an isomorphic image of theirs).

Comment: @user26857 What a  clever construction. I got it. Thanks.  The construction may be generalized to obtain elements of any order in a ring with any characteristic.